# how not to update timestamp field

Tags: php, mysql

project is written on php.
There is timestamp field in mysql it updates automatically. In one case I don`t need update this field. Can I gibe instruction not to update this field in this queries without getting timestamp value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change it to `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` otherwise it will auto-update. From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html):

> In a CREATE TABLE  statement, the first TIMESTAMP column can be declared in any of the following ways:
>
> With both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clauses, the column has the current timestamp for its default value, and is automatically updated.
>
> With neither DEFAULT nor ON UPDATE clauses, it is the same as DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
>
> With a DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  clause and no ON UPDATE clause, the column has the current timestamp for its default value but is not automatically updated.

Comment: Thank you. I was using old PMA version

Answer (score 1):

Edit the column in phpMyAdmin and unselect the option for "on update current timestamp."